# Dart KeyboardEvent return false

Tags: html, input, dart, keyboard-events

I'm handeling Input in my framework the following way:

```
window.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
    _keys[e.keyCode]=true;
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

(The whole class [here](https://github.com/ViliX64/VilTAGE/blob/master/lib/input.dart))

I was used to put `return false;` at the end of my methods in Java which would indicate, that the event was taken care of. I've read that `e.stopPropagation();` should do the same thing. Unfortunately it does not.

(Try pressing space in this [sample game](http://gamejolt.com/games/arcade/entity-unchained/41009/))

The question is, how to prevent the KeyboardEvent from going through the whole document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `preventDefault` method could make the trick here:

```
window.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
...
  e.preventDefault();
});
```